# How to handle two ImageButtons on a childview of ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have created a `ExpandableList View` with some group items and corresponding child items.

I'm able to get to the child view, and access the child view properties with the help of `groupPosition` and `childPosition`.

Now I have to put two `ImageButton` on this every child view, and trigger different Intents on click of each one.

I tried to code to set the `onClickListeners` for each Image Button and get the corresponding results, but I'm facing difficulty in the **return value**, where the `getChildView` returns only one `View`.
How can I get the response for each `ImageButton` 's click?

My code is below:

```
public View getChildView (final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean    isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  
{
    final View providbtn = super.getChildView(groupPosition, childPosition, isLastChild, convertView, parent);
    final View lecvidbtn = super.getChildView(groupPosition, childPosition, isLastChild, convertView, parent);
    final ImageButton providbtn1 = (ImageButton)providbtn.findViewById(R.id.provid);
    final ImageButton lecvidbtn1 = (ImageButton)lecvidbtn.findViewById(R.id.lecvid);
    //final View childItemClicked = super.getChildView(groupPosition, childPosition, isLastChild, convertView, parent);
    //final ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)childItemClicked.findViewById(R.id.)
    //ImageButton provid = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.provid);
    providbtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Topic Proc video is: "+topic[groupPosition]+" and Chapter is "+chapter[groupPosition][childPosition], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                flag = "p";
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("topic",topic[groupPosition] );
                bundle.putString("chapter",chapter[groupPosition][childPosition] );
                Intent goHome = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VideoWeb.class);
                goHome.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(goHome);
                }
            });

            lecvidbtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Topic Lec video is: "+topic[groupPosition]+" and Chapter is "+chapter[groupPosition][childPosition], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            flag = "l";
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("topic",topic[groupPosition] );
                bundle.putString("chapter",chapter[groupPosition][childPosition] );
                Intent goHome = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VideoWeb.class);
                goHome.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(goHome);
                        }
        });


    return lecvidbtn;  //My confusion is here. How to capture the return value for any of the image buttons clicked above.?
}
```

Comment: i don't think you will be able do this, coz in listview only list items get clicked and not its children.. All its children are not focussable..

Comment: @sandy, I'm able to get the result when there is one image button, but when I added two image buttons, the method is still restricting me to use only one image button click, other imagebutton click is not responsive. This is all with the return value i'm passing I hope. i need some repair there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way

```
  public View getChildView(int groupPosition,int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         View v = null;
          if( convertView != null )
              v = convertView;
          else
              v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, parent, false); 
          String c = (String)getChild( groupPosition, childPosition );
          final int grpPos = groupPosition;
          final int childPos = childPosition;
              ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton)v.findViewById( R.id.imageButton1);
              ImageButton button2 = (ImageButton)v.findViewById( R.id.imageButton2);
       // and set onClickListener to this two button
              button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                  Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Topic Proc video is: "+topic[groupPosition]+" and Chapter is "+chapter[groupPosition][childPosition], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    flag = "p";
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("topic",topic[groupPosition] );
                    bundle.putString("chapter",chapter[groupPosition][childPosition] );
                    Intent goHome = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VideoWeb.class);
                    goHome.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(goHome);

                 }
              )};
              button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Topic Lec video is: "+topic[groupPosition]+" and Chapter is "+chapter[groupPosition][childPosition], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    flag = "l";
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("topic",topic[groupPosition] );
                    bundle.putString("chapter",chapter[groupPosition][childPosition] );
                    Intent goHome = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VideoWeb.class);
                    goHome.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(goHome);

                 }
              )};
          return v;

      }
```

and **child_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#ebebeb"
android:layout_height="50dp">
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:src="@drawable/button1" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:src="@drawable/button2" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Khan, this is working good, but apart from two image buttons, I have a textView in child_row.xml, which shows the text next to these two buttons. I have not changed my child_row.xml, but updated the code with your suggestions, the text disappeared. I'm able to see the correct text in the Toast I put on these tow image buttons, but the actual text which is supposed to show on the childview disappeared.

Comment: first of all you have to make your **child_row.xml** according to your design  i have just shown demo xml not for two button make layout according to your requirement and than you are able to see text too i think your textview is hide behind the button check your layout design

Comment: Yep, my mistake, I realized that i didn't set the text to the textView properly. Thanks much for your help.